# Flink Stream SQL order by

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I have a streaming input, say stock price data (including multiple stocks), and I want to do a ranking by their price every 1 minutes. The ranking is based on all stocks' latest price and needs to sort all of them no matter if it was updated in the previous 1 minute or not. I tried to use ORDER BY in flink stream SQL.

I failed to implement my logic and I am confused about two parts:

1. Why can `ORDER BY` only use a time attribute as primary and only support `ASC`? How can I implement an order by an other type like price?
2. What does the below SQL (from the Flink document) mean? There is no window and there is no window so I assume the SQL will be executed immediately for each order come in, in that case, it looks meaningless to sort one element.

**[Update]: When I read the code of ProcimeSortProcessFunction.scala, it seems that Flink sorts the elements received during the next one millisecond.**

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders
ORDER BY orderTime
```

Finally, is there a way to implement my logic in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ORDER BY` in streaming queries are difficult to compute because we don't want to update the whole result when we have to emit a result that would need to go to the beginning of the result table. Therefore, we only support `ORDER BY time-attribute` if we can guarantee that the results have (roughly) increasing timestamps.

In the future (Flink 1.6 or later), we will also support some queries like `ORDER BY x ASC LIMIT 10`, which will result in an updating table that contains the records with the 10 smallest `x` values.

Anyway, you cannot (easily) compute a top-k ranking per minute using a `GROUP BY` tumbling window. `GROUP BY` queries aggregate the records of group (also window in case of `GROUP BY TUMBLE(rtime, INTERVAL '1' MINUTE)`) into a single record. So there won't be multiple records per minute but just one.

If you'd like a query to compute top-10 on field `a` per minute you would need a query similar to this one:

```
SELECT a, b, c 
FROM (
  SELECT 
    a, b, c, 
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY a PARTITION BY CEIL(t TO MINUTE) BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as rank 
  FROM yourTable)
WHERE rank <= 10
```

However, such queries are not yet supported by Flink (version 1.4) because the time attribute is used in the `PARTITION BY` clause and not the `ORDER BY` clause of the `OVER` window.

Comment: Thanks Fabian, I was wrong thought the ORDER BY is calculated for the elements inside the window instead of the window result, thanks for clarify it.